# Google Form answers validation with sheet and send email to users based on it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[Data Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5KvC.png)Requirement :-

I am trying to write an Google App script to send email based on their answers while form submission for travel expenses.
i.e if form users choose  x as their city y as their per diem rate(allowance per day) script should check the google sheet attached for predefined values and if the user had entered the value more than allocated for a city then it should email admins to review the request else email users that is auto approved.

I know this can be done via if loop but pretty new to coding struggling to pull this condition any help would be great

```
function onformsubmit(e){   
  var townCity = e.values[11];
  var currency = e.values[12];
.... // other lines of function
}

function sendEmails(townCity,currency){//var imported for other function for validation
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ssid");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Rates for validation check");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var city= sheet.getRange(2, 2, 141); // Fetch the range, including the minimums column 2 for city list in data sheet
  var budget= sheet.getRange(2, 3, 141); // Fetch the range, including the minimums column 3 for allocated budget for each city in dat sheet
  var location = city.getValues(); // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var location2 = budget.getValues();
  Logger.log(townCity); // log test 
  if (townCity == location && currency == location2 ) {
    Logger.log('sendemail');}
  else if(townCity == location && currency != location2) {
    Logger.log('dontsendemail');
  } 
}
```

[latest form sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6dCp.png)

Full Code

```js
// When Form Gets submitted
function onFormSubmit(e) {
//Get information from form and set as variables
var emailAddress = e.values[1];
var clientName = e.values[4];
var StartDate = e.values[6];
var EndDate = e.values[7];
var country = e.values[9];
var townCity = e.values[8];//this value here is not been picked correctly as the contents in the column were retried by formula from all the other city columns
var amount = e.values[12];
var currency = e.values[11];
var engagementLeaderName = e.values[2];
//Logger.log('Lets see if its here'+ townCity);
}
  //funtion to validate with data sheet
function sendEmails(amount,townCity){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ssid");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Rates for validation check");
  var firstRow = 2;
  var firstCol = 2;
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1;
  var numCols = 2;
  var allocated = sheet.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, numRows, numCols).getValues();
  var index = allocated.map(function(value) {
    return value[0];
  }).indexOf(townCity);
  if (amount > allocated[index][1]) {
   // Send email:
   Logger.log('send email')
  }
}
```

[form screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq6qN.png)

Comment: Can you show what you tried till now? Do you have any code you're working on?

Comment: yep I tried a small function to get values from form Submission and validated with data sheet tried to print using Logger.log but it returned null - Here is the code updated in question

Comment: Can you share a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, of course free of sensitive information?

Comment: Sorry was away! Added the data sheet image to question! and I will be comparing it to the another data sheet

Comment: I posted an answer, let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to do the following:

- When the user submits the form, grab the values from the response (retrieved with the event object): `townCity` and `currency`.
- Retrieve the data from another sheet, which contains a list of cities (column `B`) and the allocated budget for each city (column `C`).
- Find the city the user submitted, and check its allocated budget.
- If the `currency` that was submitted by the user is higher than the allocated budget, send an email.

If that's correct, you can change your function `sendEmails` to this one:

```js
function sendEmails(townCity, currency){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ssid");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Rates for validation check");
  var firstRow = 2;
  var firstCol = 2;
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1;
  var numCols = 2;
  var allocated = sheet.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, numRows, numCols).getValues();
  var index = allocated.map(function(value) {
    return value[0];
  }).indexOf(townCity);
  if (currency > allocated[index][1]) {
    // Send email:
    // MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)
  }
}
```

In this function, predefined cities and budgets are retrieved in a single 2D array, and [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is used to find the index of the submitted city in this array. Once this index is retrieved, it is used to find the corresponding budget `allocated[index][1]` and compare it to the submitted `currency`.

#### UPDATE:

In the form, you have several questions called `Town/City for {country}`, one for each country. To know city to look for, you need to first check the response from question `Country`. If that's the case, you can use the event property [namedValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit), an object that contains the question names and values from the form submission.

It could be something like this (I'm assuming you have a question called `Currency`:

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var country = e.namedValues["Country"][0]; // Retrieve country from form submission
  var currency = e.namedValues["Amount"][0]; // Retrieve currency from form submission
  country = country.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + country.slice(1).toLowerCase(); // Transform country from all capitalized to first character capitalized
  var townCity = e.namedValues["Town/City for " + country][0]; // Look for value corresponding to this country town/city
  sendEmails(townCity, currency);
}
```

#### UPDATE 2:

The problem you were facing is that the question names are a bit different than expected:

- In the country town/city sections, all question names should have the format `Town/City for {countryName}`, while in many cases, in your form, it's `Town/City {countryName}`, without the `for`. You have to fix this for all your countries in your form (or change the script correspondingly).
- Because the format of the countries are sometimes all capitalized, `toLowerCase` has to be used for the country name to have the same format as in the following section (only first character capitalized). I added `toLowerCase` in the script to avoid this issue.
- The property you want to track for, I assume, is `Amount`, not `Currency`. I edited that in the script.

#### Notes:

- I am assuming that you already installed the form submit trigger. If that's not the case, you should install it, either [manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) or [programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically).
- I am assuming you already know how to send the email. If that's not the case, you can start by checking [MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body).

#### Reference:

- [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208710/discussion-on-answer-by-iamblichus-google-form-answers-validation-with-sheet-and).